# "Inline" array data structure from command accepting (comma separated) arguments for the elements?

Tags: arrays, tikz-datavisualization

I have the following code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
   \toprule
    Operation & List \\
    \midrule
    \texttt{create()} & \textbf{Empty} \\
    \texttt{append(1)}& \textbf{1} \\
    \texttt{append(2)} & 1, \textbf{2} \\
    \texttt{prepend(3)} & \textbf{3}, 1, \textbf{2}\\
    \texttt{insert(1,99)} & 3, \textbf{99}, 1, 2\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

I would like to box the entries of the list like so:

[image]

(in the above the row separation was increased using `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}`)

Is there any way to build a command that does something like this:

```
\inlineArray{element1, element2, ..}
```

which could be used like below ?

```
\inlineArray{1,2,3}\texttt{.append(-99)} = \inlineArray{1,2,3,\textbf{-99}}
```

[image]

Is this possible ? I know that arrays can be draw in Tikz but I want something
that could be used inline. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can propose a syntax such as

```
\inlineArray{1,2,3,*-99}
```

where the leading asterisk means typesetting the item in boldface. There is also an option to set the minimum width of the cells (default 1.5em).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\inlineArray}{ O{1.5em} m }
 {% #1 = optional width for all items, #2 = list of items
  \group_begin:
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
  \firstuser_array:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  \group_end:
 }

\seq_new:N \l_firstuser_array_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l_firstuser_array_out_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \firstuser_array:nn
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_firstuser_array_in_seq { #2 }
  \ensuremath{\vphantom{\Big|}}
  \seq_if_empty:NTF \l_firstuser_array_in_seq
   {
    \textbf{Empty}
   }
   {
    \__firstuser_array_process:n { #1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__firstuser_array_process:n
 {
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_firstuser_array_out_seq \l_firstuser_array_in_seq
   {
    \makebox[\dim_max:nn { #1 } { \width+1em }] { \__firstuser_array_item:n { ##1 } }
   }
  \begin{tabular}{ | *{100}{c|} }
  \hline
  \seq_use:Nn \l_firstuser_array_out_seq { & } \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__firstuser_array_item:n
 {
  \str_if_eq:eeTF { \str_head:n { #1 } } { * }
   {
    \boldmath $\tl_tail:n { #1 }$
   }
   {
    $#1$
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff



\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
   \toprule
    Operation & List \\
    \midrule
    \texttt{create()}     & \inlineArray{} \\
    \texttt{append(1)}    & \inlineArray{*1} \\
    \texttt{append(2)}    & \inlineArray{1, *2} \\
    \texttt{prepend(3)}   & \inlineArray{*3, 1, *2} \\
    \texttt{insert(1,99)} & \inlineArray{3, *-99, 1, 2} \\
\midrule % just to show the option
    \texttt{prepend(3)}   & \inlineArray[3.2em]{*3, 1, *2} \\
    \texttt{insert(1,99)} & \inlineArray[3.2em]{3, *-99, 1, 2} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

$\inlineArray{1,2,3}\texttt{.append(-99)} = \inlineArray{1,2,3,*-99}$

$\inlineArray{1,2,3}\texttt{.append(-99)} = \inlineArray[3.2em]{1,2,3,*-99}$

\end{document}
```

The list is split at commas; if the resulting sequence of items is empty, just `\textbf{Empty}` is delivered. Otherwise each item is adorned with code that will produce a box of the desired width (the value of the optional argument or the natural width plus 1em, whichever is largest). Then a `tabular` is delivered.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like that:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \inlineArray { m }
  {
    \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { #1 }
    \begin { tabular } { | * { 20 } { c | } }
    \hline
    \clist_use:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { & } \\
    \hline
    \end { tabular }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\inlineArray{1,2,3}\texttt{.append(99)} = \inlineArray{1,2,3,$\mathbf{-99}$}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]